# 'Transitioning between View Controllers from an NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'd like to know what is the best way to transition back and forth between two view controllers from an `NSObject` outside of the code for those two view controllers in iOS 9. 
For example, I have..
    `GameViewcontroller.h`
    `GameViewController.m`
    `TableViewController.h`
    `TableViewController.m`
    `Helper.h`
   `Helper.m`

I need `Helper.m` which is an NSObject, to be able to call a segue or transitional code so `GameViewController` and `TableViewController` transition between themselves without causing any memory or assertion issues.

Comment: Are you having an NSObject class??

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention that. Helper.m is an NSObject. @AkashKR

Comment: You mean it's an `NSObject` *sub*-class.  Just expose a method in the view controller and call that from this `NSObject` sub-class.  The method can then do the normal thing.  How you get a reference to the view controller might be your next question, and that's probably obtained using `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]` (and casting it to the correct `UIViewController` sub-class).

Comment: What kind of thing lets `Helper` know that the switches should happen?

Comment: I have GKMatchMaker code in Helper.m that when it finds a match, it should make GameViewController.m transition to TableViewController.m.  When the match is over, TableViewController.m will transition back to GameViewController.m.  When a new match is found, GameViewController.m will again transition to TableViewController.m.  @PhillipMills

Comment: Follow this link, https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/